# How to assign this list of id's to video.list (id = ) and make it return more than 50 results?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, youtube-data-api

I create a script that covert YouTube video links into id's:

```
print(link_data.head)
```

I have 100 rows in 1 column

```
0    tSbA3J_enCA
1    jWOgDXnqxi8
2    uNZH7zlZ-b4
3    SgXwnKTHRdM
4    TuN_vVoEqf4
..           ...
96   SxSQ29eUyfo
97   dmPb-gZgaBk
98   fA1Jzm9fK38
99   HNdQ6yXQmLE
100  Z8FdzNwSC3c
```

How to assign this`link_data` to `id_list_data` and make it return more than 50 results?

```
id_list_data = 

results = youtube.videos().list(id = id_list_data, part ='snippet').execute()
for result in results.get('items', []):
        print(result ['id'])
        print(result ['snippet']['channelTitle'])
        print(result ['snippet']['title'])
        print(result ['snippet']['description'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As YouTube Data API v3 Videos: list endpoint has a `maxResults` of 50, you have to call `youtube.videos().list(...)` with at most 50 `id`s.

```
maxResults = 50

for i in range(ceil(len(link_data.head) / maxResults)):
    id_list_data = link_data.head[i * maxResults:(i + 1) * maxResults]
    results = youtube.videos().list(id = id_list_data, part ='snippet').execute()
    for result in results.get('items', []):
            print(result ['id'])
            print(result ['snippet']['channelTitle'])
            print(result ['snippet']['title'])
            print(result ['snippet']['description'])
```

Comment: May deleting of ```maxResults```   lead to increasing of data output?

If no, is there a way how can I loop it to cycle though the list?

Comment: Deleting `maxResults` doesn't make sense, it's not an optional argument in my code above. Note that my code proceed to such cycle though the list as far as I understand your comment.